# Replacing lost power adapter using low-cost alternative

Tags: electricity

I guess most people know the issue of losing a power adaptor for one of their devices. In my case I just lost [this kind of adapter](https://tangent-audio.com/products/17-accessories-amp-spare-parts/39-power-adaptor-tangent-fjord/). I don't see how these adapters should be that expensive to manufacture and I guess there should be some overlap in terms of electrical specifications for different adapters. Is there any way to find a suitable low-cost alternative to Amazon or similar site for a somewhat uncommon adapter such as the one I've just lost?

note: transformer is for 220V (Europe), so answers need to reflect that

Comment: Some are just rare.  Unfortunate standard(s) have not been established.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it looks like a request for product recommendation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of "universal" adapters costing *far* less than the OEM replacement. There are a few factors to check to match the original:

1. Output voltage should be within 5% off of the OEM supply. Check the input voltage on the device, if you can't find the output of the supply.
2. Output connector *must* match that of your device. Be sure of the polarity, as well (often center positive, shell negative, but not *always*.) Try a universal power supply (PS) with multiple connectors, unless you can find a PS that is designed to match your device.
3. Mains voltage and connectors should match your region, e.g. 230V in G.B. or 120V in U.S.A). Some newer "wall warts" may work from 110V to 240V.
4. The PS must be able to supply *at least* the rated current of the original, but can be higher.

Buy from a reputable source... there are rare cases of poor electrical isolation between mains and device, which is shocking!